# Are there any time-limited side quests?

Tags: dying-light-2

As you progress in Dying Light 2, you'll eventually have to choose a faction. There are two factions: Survivor and Peace Keeper (rumor has it that you can also side with the Renegades... but I haven't confirmed it yet).

I assume they have faction-limited quests in both main and sub, but are there any time-limited side quests (i.e. before and after choosing factions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several side quests that have to be taken, and completed, within a specific period of time in order to be able to complete them.
In order to prevent missing any it is best to complete any side quests as soon as they become available to avoid that risk.
There is not currently a full list of them available online, so doing them as you are able prevents that risk to begin with.

[GameFAQ: Missable side quests](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/288759-dying-light-2-stay-human/79890063).

[Reddit: [LIST] Missable Side Quests due to Story Progression quests](https://www.reddit.com/r/dyinglight/comments/stwe3m/list_missable_side_quests_due_to_story_progression/)

Side note, some side quests for a specific zone can be different depending on whether you give faction control to Survivors, versus PK.

Answer (score 1):

After playing for about 40 hours, I noticed that some of the side quests I've received were automatically removed from the quest list (Journal). Moreover, this also happened after I chose to side with PK, so I'm sure that there are time-limited (not exactly sure when though) side quests, as well as faction-specific quests.

Possibly, both of these could have happened when I've decided to give control of the water tower/power station, so I'll have a look into it once I've decided to create another save to play as the Survivor side... Probably not anytime soon.